# Using string interpolation for function call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

Is there a way to call the following function using ES6 syntax:

```
let type = 'Line'
new Chartkick.${ type }Chart(el, this.data)
```

with the hopes of generating:

```
new Chartkick.LineChart(el, this.data)
```

Comment: I don't think so, however you can use this syntax: ```let type = 'LineChart';``` and then ```new Chartkick[type](el, this.data);``` this is not an es6 specific syntax however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need any string interpolation for this. It's just [standard dynamic property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) with bracket notation:

```
new Chartkick[type+"Chart"](el, this.data);
```

Of course you could use an ES6 template literal instead of the string concatenation, but I don't think it boosts readability a lot:

```
new Chartkick[`${ type }Chart`](el, this.data);
```